# Loop through rows in particular column then execute if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all rows (there is 1000's of rows) in column 'AQ' and if value = "Salary Sacrifice" then I want to display "SALSC" in column 'AP' same row. Here is my code I have so far:

```
Dim payCodeDescription As String
Dim paycodevalue As String

payCodeDescription = Range("AQ52").Value

If payCodeDescription = "Salary Sacrifice" Then paycodevalue = "SALSC"
ElseIf payCodeDescription = "GrossPay-Overpaid" Then paycodevalue = "OVERP"
End If

Range("AP52").Value = paycodevalue
```

Is there any way I could turn this into a loop instead of hard coding?

I would use this if formuala...

```
=IF(AQ52="Salary Sacrifice","SALSC",IF(AQ52="GrossPay-Overpaid","OVERP",""))
```

but this replaces the values if the condition is false and I need it to do nothing if the value is false.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched at least how to loop trough columns? There are like thousands of examples here in SO...

Comment: Autofilter Col AQ on "Salary Sacrifice" and then work with the filtered range. That will be much faster.

Comment: (1) Why are you using VBA for this? (2) Filtering would be quicker than looping (3) Search for loops, there must be gazillions of examples online.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes and i cannot get it to work at all. never used vba before. didnt show my loop as it was a complete disaster lol

Comment: i have no idea why i never thought of filtering. this is so much better than using vba. thanks for the suggestion folks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking to use VBA, something like the code below will help:

```
Sub LoopThroughRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AQ").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column AQ

For i = 2 To LastRow
'loop from row 2 to the Last row
    If ws.Cells(i, "AQ").Value = "Salary Sacrifice" Then ws.Cells(i, "AP").Value = "SALSC"
    If ws.Cells(i, "AQ").Value = "GrossPay-Overpaid" Then ws.Cells(i, "AP").Value = "OVERP"
    'process your conditional statements
Next i
'next row
End Sub
```

The faster method as mentioned in the comments would be Filtering the data instead of looping through individual rows, the code below is an example of that:

```
Sub FilterRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
ws.Cells.AutoFilter
If ws.FilterMode = True Then ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
'apply Autofilter and make sure we show all data
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AQ").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column AQ

ws.Range("$A$1:$AQ$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=43, Criteria1:="Salary Sacrifice"
'filter by Criteria on Column 43, AQ
ws.Range("AP2:AP" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "SALSC"
'fill visible rows in Column AP with the desired text

ws.Range("$A$1:$AQ$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=43, Criteria1:="GrossPay-Overpaid"
ws.Range("AP2:AP" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "OVERP"

If ws.FilterMode = True Then ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
'clear the Filter to show all data again.
End Sub
```